# My picture slideshow is not cooperating with my footer. Part of the slideshow is behind the footer and it won't scroll down

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

So I copied over a javascript picture slideshow and placed it in `section` tags inside the `body`. When I go to preview the site, a portion of the slideshow is behind my `<footer>` and I can't view it. It won't allow me to scroll down to view the rest of the picture slideshow.

I think it's something with the scroll bars or the size of the body, I'm not sure.

I'm very new to HTML/CSS and my code may be messy and some parts redundant or unnecessary, so any constructive criticism is also welcome.

Here is my html:

```
<section>
        <div class="container">
            <img class="mySlides" src="https://i.imgur.com/cWNxWqs.jpg?1" style="width:100%">
            <img class="mySlides" src="img_lights.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img class="mySlides" src="img_mountains.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <img class="mySlides" src="img_forest.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
            <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
        </div>
        <script>
            var slideIndex = 1;
            showDivs(slideIndex);

            function plusDivs(n) {
              showDivs(slideIndex += n);
            }

            function showDivs(n) {
              var i;
              var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
              if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
              if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
              for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                 x[i].style.display = "none";  
              }
              x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
            }
        </script>
    </section>
</body>
<footer>
    <div class="container" style="clear: both">
        <ul>
            <li style="list-style-type: none;">Contact Me</li>
            <li style="list-style-type: none;">Connect with Me</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</footer>
```

And my CSS:

```
footer{
    font: 15px/1.5 Times New Roman;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    padding:50px 0px;
    background:#9360DB;
    border-top:#6163d0 3px solid;
    clear: both;
    position: fixed;
}  

footer ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

footer li{
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
    color: white;

}

section{
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you want the footer to be fixed to the window. So the solution should be to add `margin-bottom` to the `section` element. The margin-bottom should have the same value or greater than the height of the `footer` element. Refer the below snippet. Also please note, I am setting the properties `box-sizing:border-box` so that the padding is included in the height calculation. Also the height is set for the footer to `height:135px`. So the `margin-bottom` for the section element is set to `margin-bottom:150px`.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = x.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
footer {
  font: 15px/1.5 Times New Roman;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0px;
  background: #9360DB;
  border-top: #6163d0 3px solid;
  clear: both;
  position: fixed;
}

footer ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

footer li {
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
  color: white;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 150px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <img class="mySlides" src="https://i.imgur.com/cWNxWqs.jpg?1" style="width:100%">
    <img class="mySlides" src="img_lights.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img class="mySlides" src="img_mountains.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img class="mySlides" src="img_forest.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
    <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
  </div>
</section>
<footer>
  <div class="container" style="clear: both">
    <ul>
      <li style="list-style-type: none;">Contact Me</li>
      <li style="list-style-type: none;">Connect with Me</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add bottom margin to section equal to footer height**

```
 section {
   margin-bottom: 200px;  //equal to footer height
 }
```